# OpenCV changing brightness and contrast

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am having trouble changing the brightness of an image. My code is:

```
float alpha = 1.0f;
int beta = -20; //brightness, negative for darkening(?)
image.convertTo(image, -1, alpha, beta);
```

Whatever values I choose for alpha and beta the image becomes brighter.
Should the `convertTo` function also be able to darken the image?

It seems I may have to use `saturate_cast`, but I am not sure where I would use this in the above example.

Comment: [This doc page](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/basic_linear_transform/basic_linear_transform.html) shows how to use `saturate_cast`.  Also note that this example is doing the bri/con operation on a pixel-basis.

Comment: What datatype is your `image` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with OpenCV or my above code.
This is part of an Android project, and usually the ndk-build tool compiled my C++ files when I ran the app.
Somehow my Eclipse configuration has been changed (broken), and none of my C++ files were being compiled. 
That is why doing various edits to my code, there was no effect on output. After manually calling ndk-build before running the app, it now works as it should.

What is wrong with my Eclipse configuration is a different story.

Comment: but what if our image is already in `RGBA` format then we also need to deal with the alpha ?

Answer (score 2):

1) I just verified. It was darkened properly. Are you sure that it really became brighter? How are you checking that?

2) You don't need to use functions like convertTo since you are not converting anything. Much more readable way would be:

```
image = alpha*image + beta;
```